# UITableView scrollable into UIVIewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have simple `UIViewController` with two subviews as shown on picture below

[image]

What i'm trying to do is when scroll down `UITableView` content to push out also `UIView` on top.

Let's say for example i want to replicate `UITableView` with Header behaviour

Is it possible whiteout using table header?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Override `scrollView` delegate method and detect is user scrolled in that direction. Manually hide `view` according to scrolled distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, this is about how it should work

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let yPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if (yPosition > yourView.frame.size.height) {
        return;
    }
    yourView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -yPosition, yourView.frame.size.width, yourView.frame.size.height)
    tableView.frame = GRectMake(0, yourView.frame.origin.y + self.yourView.frame.size.height,  tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height)
}
```

You might have to adjust the frame positioning logic a, this came from the top of my head.